# Passing variable from MailMessage to notifications email blade template

Tags: laravel

Can I pass a `foo` variable to the `MailMessage`:

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->subject('Hello : ' . __('Verify Email Address'))
    ->line(__('Please click the button below to verify your email address.'))
    ->action(__('Verify Email Address'), $verificationUrl)
    ->line(__('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
```

in order to use it anywhere in the `resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php` template file:

```
{{ foo }}
```

Answer (score -3):

yes you can :

Ex :

```
Mail::to($email)
    ->send(new NotifiyNewOrder($datayouwanttopass));
```

and in Mail, :

```
public $datayouwanttopass;

public function __construct($datayouwanttopass)
{
    $this->datayouwanttopass = $datayouwanttopass;
}


public function build()
{
    return $this->
    from('set the sender email')
        ->subject('subject')
        ->view('the view here.');
}
```